# Maps for IOS 7.1 Application

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, mapbox

Currently trying to include maps within my ios 7.1 app. Essentially what I am trying to do is read in markers and display them on my map. I have a considerable number of marker to display some hundreds. Is it possible using mapkit to read in from a sqllite table these markers and display them.

thanks in advance

Comment: What about Apple's own `MapKit`?

Comment: Needs more information still

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox is built on top of leaflet, you can use that.

Also, you can always use a uiwebview and put something in there.

But I do suggest either google, or Apple maps, they are pretty stable.
I tried using mapbox in an iPhone project before, but ended up sticking to Apple maps (mapKit), if you know what you want to do you can create some awesome stuff.

Hope that helps?